# C++ и windows embedded handheld 6.5

Tags: c++, windows

Работаю очень много с разными сканерами которые все работают на windows embedded handheld 6.5

В частности один из основных сканеров это Motorola MC67 Mobile Computer

Мне хотелось бы сделать "программу" которая могла бы при запуске сама указывать все необходимые мне настройки WIFI сети и GPRS подключения изменить везде часовые пояса .

Слишком много времени у меня на это уходит и просто скучно )

Comment: *Мне хотелось бы сделать*  - ну сделайте... А если что-то не получается - тогда создавайте вопрос, описывающий конкретную проблему.

Comment: я не програмист и очень хотел бы получить наставление с вашей стороны в каком направлении двигаться и что нужно почитать и не более

Comment: [книги и учебные ресурсы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B8+%D0%B8+%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5+%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81%D1%8B)

Comment: Читайте документацию на сканеры. Если производителем там предусмотрено то, что Вам надо, то там описано как это сделать. Если производителем там НЕ предусмотрено то, что Вам надо, то вряд-ли кто-то вообще сможет это сделать.

Comment: ну и макросы никто не отменял =)

Comment: @helldrg да, а ты знаешь макросы для windows embedded handheld 6.5 ?

Comment: неа, только 8-кой пользуюсь